# converting Images into music masterpieces 

Tags: composition, music, image

I wrote a article on this subject at my blog and was wondering people thoughts on it.

As in do you think that these forms of experimental music will they ever be able to build a real following like other types of experimental Music have ?

[composition music](http://compositions-of-alphacore.blogspot.com/2010/05/composition-music-created-from-images.html)  created with Images.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends:

1. Is the music good/popular, which means that how it got produced (ie: from an image) shouldn't matter.
2. On the flip side, geeks (like me) that love the process almost as much as the end product might climb on board and it could gain momentum.

I've come across many [Max/MSP](http://cycling74.com/products/maxmspjitter/) patches that explore this idea. Although they mostly use brightness/color/saturation of images to affect sounds either through [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) or other sound manipulating techniques. Apart from the [software](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Audio/Sound-of-an-Image.shtml) linked on [your article](http://compositions-of-alphacore.blogspot.com/2010/05/composition-music-created-from-images.html), I haven't seen MIDI being utilized. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I use Abaltat Muse to 'compose' music for use behind video. It works reasonably well with some tweaking but perhaps this is because video already has a dynamic over time that a still image lacks.

Indeed, Abaltat really just matches the dynamics of a few patterns to those of the moving image.

That said, it is useful and generates results that seem to work well

Mike